# Using .toggle() jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery code, and want to toggle it. When I use

```
$('#checkb').toggle(function() });
```

It does not toggle

```
$('#checkb').bind('click',function() {
    var PackagePrice = $('#specs_packageprice').text();
    var Quantity = $('#specs_quantity').text();
    var ItemPrice = $('#specs_itempr').text();
    var Unit = $('#specs_unit').text();     
    var calc = Unit*ItemPrice;

    $('#final_value').text(calc);                               
});
```

What could be wrong?

Thanks
Jean

Comment: It would help if you show the code as how you are trying to use it....or is that first line of code how you are really trying to use it? .toggle() requires two arguments, where you would normally pass a callback function call to both arguments, one for each "toggle state". All you have listed there is a single argument, invoking an empty anonymous function.

Comment: Your code looks like it's missing chunks - `toggle` line has a bare `}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#checkb').toggle( function () { // Every even click
  var PackagePrice = $('#specs_packageprice').text();
  var Quantity = $('#specs_quantity').text();
  var ItemPrice = $('#specs_itempr').text();
  var Unit = $('#specs_unit').text();     
  var calc = Unit*ItemPrice;
  $('#final_value').text(calc);                               
},
function () { // Every odd click
  // Do something here
});
```

**EDIT :**
Toogle seems to be messing with checkbox. You can try

```
$('#checkb').click( function () {
  if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
    //do stuff if the checkbox is checked
  } else {
    //do stuff if the checkbox isn't checked
  }
```

);

Comment: Here #checkb is the id of the checkbox.  It works fine, but the checkbox is not getting checked

Answer (score 1):

Set up a function to handle this like so:

```
function calc_on_click(){
    var PackagePrice = $('#specs_packageprice').text();
    var Quantity = $('#specs_quantity').text();

    var ItemPrice = $('#specs_itempr').text();
    var Unit = $('#specs_unit').text();     
    var calc = Unit*ItemPrice;

    $('#final_value').text(calc);

    return false;
}
```

Then just bind a click element to your sum button!

```
$("#checkb").click(calc_on_click);
//Or if its explicitly a toggle needed:
$("#checkb").toggle(calc_on_click,calc_on_click); //On / Off
```

Then that function should do what you need it to do.